# Как использовать адреса полученные через il2cpp dumper

Tags: c#, dump

Как использовать адреса функций из dump.cs в game guardian? Я пробовал hex поиск но ничего не нашлось. Пробовал перейти по адресу, но тоже безрезультатно. Какой от них смысл в game guardian и как их там использовать?